# How to keep both rows of legend center justified and positioned at the center of the plot when legend.position = "top"

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

**When I use**

`legend.position = "top"`

I can make the legend center justified but left positioned.

**When I use**

`legend.position=c(.1, .9)`

I can put the legend center positioned but left justified (by manipulating these numbers).

**None of these is what I want.**

**For example**

```
dat<-structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Income = c(50, 
101, 1001, 600), Members = c(10, 12, 14, 16), Status = c("New", "Old", "New", "Old")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

View(dat)

ggplot()+ 
 geom_point(data=dat,aes(x=Name,y=Income,colour=Status,
             size= Members), 
             shape = 20) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",  #this keeps the legend center aligned but left positioned
        #legend.position=c(.1, .9), #manipulating these numbers I can put the legend center aligned but left justified
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'mm'))+ 
        guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2))
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the full code.  For me, the legends are centered when I run your code.  Is there another theme or aesthetic that's being applied this command?  Moreover, are you just using `ggplot2` or do you have another add-on that changes the theme?  It could be overwriting some of your theme elements.  Otherwise, you can try to add `legend.justification='center'` to force-align the legend centered.

Comment: legend.justification='center' did not work

Comment: Again - your code actually seemed to work perfectly for me.  The legends were centered above one another and centered within the plot area.  When code "works" on one R installation and "doesn't" on another, it's often due to versions of packages not being the same or loading order of libraries.  I recommend you try to start a new R session (with no packages loaded), then load `ggplot2` ,then run your code.  See if that fixes it.  If not, I'd use `install.packages()` to update your `ggplot2` package.  It's possible your version is different and causing the glitch.

Comment: Works fine for me too (centred at the top). Are you adding another `theme_****()` but not showing us? This will override your previous theme which modifies the legends. For example, if you add `+ theme_classic() at the end, your legends will appear on the right-hand side.

Comment: I did not add another `theme_****()`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want? You want the titles to be both center positioned and center aligned, correct? If so, I disagree with the above commenters as, though it looks good, the alignment is "left" not "centered." Is that the issue here?

Comment: Yes. That is the issue. Any solutions?